# Алгоритм комментариев

Tags: php

Ребят есть вопрос, я делаю систему комментариев как у вконтакте, у меня будет 2 вида комментариев: родитель и потомок. Хочу спросить, на сколько эффективно использовать следующий алгоритм, - сначала достаём из бд все комментарии где parent = 0 // т.е те комментарии у которых нет родителей, далее выводим всё циклом в нём используем функцию, которая принимает id текущего коммента т.е родителя, а в этой функции мы уже ищем комменты где родитель = комменту из цикла, и если есть выводим

Comment: Советую прочитать:

- [Иерархические структуры данных и Doctrine](http://habrahabr.ru/post/46659/)
- [Строим Nested Set дерево без рекурсии](http://habrahabr.ru/post/153861/)

Answer (score 3):

```
select `children`.`text`,`children`.`id`,`children`.`parent_id`, if(`parent`.`id` is null, 'parent','children') as `type` from messages as children left join messages as parent on parent.id=children.parent_id
```

Я бы как-то так запросил. В итоге, получаем одновременно список родителей и детей с дополнительным полем type=children/parent